# append key and value in dictionary simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of headers and values coming from a web scrapped page. But once i pass it to a for loop i get a very bigger list. In code i am iterating the headers and the web elements and storing them in a list, not sure why

```
header = ['h1','h2'......'h60']
Webscrapped list, in code get values like below
row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[i].text -> something like this values [1,2.........5]

here i got 'i' till 60 where the headers is also till 60, so i pass the same 'i' value for key and value parsing
```

**Expected Size:**
The actual web page table size is [60 cols * 9 rows] But i get pandas dataframe around [60 cols * 580+ rows]

**Code i tried**

```
value_list = []

header_list = ['h1','h2','h3',.......,'h60']

for i in range(0,len(header_list)):
    for row in table_trs:
        value_list.append({
            header_list[i]:row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[i].text
        })
df = pd.DataFrame(value_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to do this:

```py
value_list = []

header_list = ['h1','h2','h3',.......,'h60']

for row in table_trs:
    value_list.append({
        header: row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[i].text
        for i, header in enumerate(header_list)
    })
df = pd.DataFrame(value_list)
```

i.e. each element in `value_list` should be a complete dictionary representing a row in the table

whereas in your original code you made a dictionary per column per row

I think you could also do it like:

```py
value_list = []

header_list = ['h1','h2','h3',.......,'h60']

for row in table_trs:
    value_list.append([
        row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[i].text
        for i in range(0, len(header_list))
    ])

df = pd.DataFrame(value_list, columns=header_list)
```

to avoid repeating the headers in every row (more efficient if you have a lot of rows to build)

Comment: 'list index out of range' this error it shows for both the codes

Comment: row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[i] here the i is different values for all, for eg: if i -> 2 then the values are [100, 200, 300...]

Comment: your original code would have had the same issue. it sounds like there is a `row` with less `<td>` than there are headers

Comment: you were right the row was less than td, now it works like a charm thanks